# MATLAB C MEX API : fread directly into struct?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

In pure C, I can open a binary file and read the file header directly into a struct pretty simply. In MATLAB's C-MEX API, it seems to be a much more tedious procedure. I have to 1: Initialize the struct from an array of field names. 2: Initialize a typed `mxArray` for each struct field individually. 3: `fread` into the `mxArray` for each struct field individually. 4: Assign an `mxArray` to each struct field individually (by number or name).

Is there a simpler way to fread data directly into a MATLAB struct?

```
#pragma pack(2)  
typedef struct file_header  
{  
    int64_t preamble;  
    int16_t version;  
    int16_t mode;  
    int8_t software_name[32];  
    int32_t content;  
    // ...  
    // other fields  
} file_header_t;  

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])  
{  
    char *file_name = mxArrayToString(prhs[0]);  
    // read file header (C) /////////////////////////////////////////////////  
    file_header_t das_header;  
    FILE *fptr = fopen(file_name, "rb");  
    fread(&das_header, sizeof(file_header_t), 1, fptr);  
    fclose(fptr);  

    // read file header (MATLAB) ////////////////////////////////////////////  
    const int n_field = 37;  
    static const char *field_name[] = {  
        "preamble",  
        "version",  
        "mode",  
        "software_name",  
        "content"  
        // ...  
        // other field names  
    };  
    // init matlab struct  
    plhs[0] = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, n_field, field_name);  
    // init mxArray containers for struct fields  
    mxArray *preamble = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxINT64_CLASS, mxREAL);  
    mxArray *version = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxINT16_CLASS, mxREAL);  
    mxArray *mode = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxINT16_CLASS, mxREAL);  
    mxArray *software_name = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 32, mxINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);  
    mxArray *content = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);  
    // ...  
    // mxArray *all *subsequent *struct *fields;  

    fptr = fopen(file_name, "rb");  
    fread((int64_t*)mxGetData(preamble), 8, 1, fptr);  
    fread((int16_t*)mxGetData(version), 2, 1, fptr);  
    fread((int16_t*)mxGetData(mode), 2, 1, fptr);  
    fread((int8_t*)mxGetData(software_name), 1, 32, fptr);  
    fread((int32_t*)mxGetData(content), 4, 1, fptr);  
    // ...  
    // fread((type*)mxGetData(field_name), sizeof(type), 1, fptr);  

    fclose(fptr);  

    // assign field values  
    mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], 0, 0, preamble);  
    mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], 0, 1, version);  
    mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], 0, 2, mode);  
    mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], 0, 3, software_name);  
    mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], 0, 4, content);  
    // ...  
    // mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], 0, k, field_name);  
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it in a MATLAB struct? You may as well just code this in MATLAB, so its easier

Comment: In spite of it being a headache, low-level file I/O is much faster in C than MATLAB. The non-header portions of these files are 100 MiB to 1 GiB in size. The header encodes instructions needed to read the data portion of that file.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way. Its more verbose, but not much longer than C. You'd still needs mallocs and asignments. Yeah, its not ideal, but I am not sure there is an alternative

Comment: A MATLAB struct is not the same as a C struct. Each field is a separate matrix, with its own bit of memory on the heap. A C struct is a contiguous bit of memory that you can pretend is a single char buffer. The simplest solution is to write an M-file function to load the header, and call this function from your MEX-file.

Comment: And if this header contains only relevant information to read the actual data, then you don't need to pass this back to MATLAB, right? Just read the header into a C struct, load the main data, and pass that main data back to MATLAB.